# URL Rewrite index.php?domain=domain.com to /domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

I have .htaccess this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?domain=$1
```

If url domain.com/goo is show the result, but if url domain.com/goo.gl is not  found, whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to comprehend your current rule you are trying to remove "." in matched string even though the rule is incorrect try with below we are matching the string fully leaving none.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?domain=$1
```